# Polymer two way data binding

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have defined a polymer element

```
    Polymer({
        is: 'disco-ccontrol',

        properties: {
            midiValue: {
                type: Number,
                value: 0,
                observer: '_valueChanged',
                notify: true
            },
            channel: {
                type: Number,
                value: 0
            },
            channelNumber: {
                type: Number,
                value: 0
            },
            ref: {
                type: Object,
                computed: '_computeRef(channel, channelNumber)'
            }
        },

        _computeRef: function(channel, channelNumber) {

            var ref = new Firebase("https://incandescent-inferno-8405.firebaseio.com/user/"+channel+"/"+channelNumber);
            ref.on("value", function(data) {
               this.midiValue = data.val().value;
            });

            return ref;
        },

        _valueChanged: function() {
            var message = { value: this.midiValue, channel: this.channel, channelNumber: this.channelNumber };
            if (this.ref) {
                this.ref.set(message);
            } 
        }

    });
```

I use this element in another element (parent element)

```
<disco-ccontrol midi-value="{{value}}" channel="{{channel}}" cn="{{channelNumber}}"></disco-ccontrol>
```

When I adapt the value property in the parent it propagates to the child. When I change the value property in the child (i.e in disco-ccontrol) it doesn't propagate up. What am I doing wrong to establish a two way binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function

```
ref.on("value", function(data) {
    this.midiValue = data.val().value;
});
```

the `this` keyword is is not bound to the Polymer element. Thus your are not setting the midiValue on the correct object. You can bind `this` to the Polymer element using `bind`.

```
ref.on("value", function(data) {
    this.midiValue = data.val().value;
}.bind(this);
```